# Flume HDFS Sink Write error "no protocol: value"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

When trying to run a flume job I am getting the error given below. I am running this on a cloudera setup.

- Kafka is the source
- Morphline is used as an interceptor with avro records getting created from it.
- Sink is HDFS

The exact same files (morphline, avro schema etc., flume config) on a test environment. But in another environment it throws this error.

```
2019-07-15 14:24:17,669 WARN org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter: Caught IOException writing to HDFSWriter (no protocol: value). Closing file (hdfs://8.8.8.8:8020/user/hive/warehouse/folder/folder/FlumeData.1563162656585.tmp) and rethrowing exception.
2019-07-15 14:24:17,670 INFO org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing hdfs://8.8.8.8:8020/user/hive/warehouse/folder/folder/FlumeData.1563162656585.tmp
2019-07-15 14:24:17,670 ERROR org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink: process failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer.flush(AvroEventSerializer.java:187)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.close(HDFSDataStream.java:131)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:327)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:323)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:701)
        at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:698)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-07-15 14:24:17,671 ERROR org.apache.flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:451)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:67)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer.flush(AvroEventSerializer.java:187)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.close(HDFSDataStream.java:131)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:327)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$3.call(BucketWriter.java:323)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:701)
        at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:698)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        ... 1 more
```

I was able to locate the relevant code on flume:
https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java (line:602)

```
// write the event
try {
  sinkCounter.incrementEventDrainAttemptCount();
  callWithTimeout(new CallRunner<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
      writer.append(event); // could block
      return null;
    }
  });
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOG.warn("Caught IOException writing to HDFSWriter ({}). Closing file (" +
      bucketPath + ") and rethrowing exception.",
      e.getMessage());
  close(true);
  throw e;
}
```

Error: `Caught IOException writing to HDFSWriter (no protocol: value). Closing file`

I am not able to workout what the error `no protocol: value` means.

I am unable to find any reference to this error in any context related to Flume and HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incerceptor protocol was missing from the configuration -- Added "file:/" in the flume configuration file which that fixed the issue.

Similar issue reference : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Flume-HDFS-sink-error-quot-unknown-protocol-hdfs-quot/td-p/19344

Comment: No, I have changed the IP and folder references to dummy reference.

Comment: I found the similar question in Cloudera Community:[Flume HDFS sink error: "unknown protocol: hdfs" ](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Flume-HDFS-sink-error-quot-unknown-protocol-hdfs-quot/td-p/19344)

Comment: Yes, it was the same mistake on my configuration as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: it's my pleasure